# Changing download directory in RSelenium using phantomjs

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, plotly, rselenium

I'd like to download a webgl graphic from plotly in R. Plotly supports this by providing an "export" which allows a (R)Selenium argument. Everything works as expected when using chrome as browser (see example 1 below)

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)
library(RSelenium)

p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()

### Example 1: Chrome (working as expecteded) ###
eCaps <- list(
  chromeOptions = 
    list(prefs = list(
      "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
      "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
      "download.default_directory" = getwd()
    )
    )
)

chrome <- rsDriver(port = 4590L, browser = "chrome", 
                geckover = NULL, iedrver = NULL, phantomver = NULL, 
                extraCapabilities = eCaps)
export(p, file = "test1.svg", selenium = chrome)
chrome[["server"]]$stop()
```

But, since I'm interested in a "silent" download in the background (without opening a browser-window) I tried the same with phantomjs. This seems to work as well but downloads the plot to my default download directory (see example 2 below). During my investigation I came across several old posts saying downloading files in phantomjs isn't possible. But since it seems possible (but uses the default directory) I thought there might be a way to set the download directory in the meantime as well.

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)
library(RSelenium)

p <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()

### Example 2: Phantom JS (Download path not settable) ###
phjs <- rsDriver(port = 4595L, browser = "phantomjs", 
               chromever = NULL, geckover = NULL, iedrver = NULL)
export(p, file = "test2.svg", selenium = phjs)
phjs[["server"]]$stop()
```

In short: How do I change the download folder in phantomjs (when using with (R)selenium)?